# How to use the React-marked library plugin to render HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I want to use this plugin to render markdown into html. [Click here for plugin](https://github.com/chjj/marked). I have everything working but  what ends up rendering is objects on the screen. I am not sure how to access them. To my understanding I don't need to. Can someone please help?

Below is the current code:

```
class ChangeText extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
      markdown: 'Heading\n=======\n\nSub-heading\n-----------\n \n### Another deeper heading\n \nParagraphs are separated\nby a blank line.\n\nLeave 2 spaces at the end of a line to do a  \nline break\n\nText attributes *italic*, **bold**, \n`monospace`, ~~strikethrough~~ .\n\nShopping list:\n\n  * apples\n  * oranges\n  * pears\n\nNumbered list:\n\n  1. apples\n  2. oranges\n  3. pears\n\nThe rain---not the reign---in\nSpain.\n\n *[Herman Fassett](https://freecodecamp.com/hermanfassett)*'
    }
  }
  updateValue(event){
    let newMarkdown = event.target.value
    this.setState({
      markdown: newMarkdown
    })
  }

  rawMarkUp(text){
    Mark.setOptions({
      gfm: true,
      tables: true,
      breaks: false,
      pedantic: false,
      sanitize: true,
      smartLists: true,
      smartypants: false
    });

    let rawhtml = Mark(text);
    console.log({__html: rawhtml});
    return {__html: rawhtml}
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <h4>Write your text here and see the mark down -></h4>
             <textarea  className="form-control" width='300' ref="textarea" value={this.state.markdown} onChange={this.updateValue.bind(this)}/>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">
             <h4>Markdown Result</h4>
            {/* <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkUp(this.state.markdown)}></div> */}
            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkUp(this.state.markdown)}></span>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ChangeText;
```

Answer (score 0):

The application works on codepen just fine. I am not sure why it doesnt want to run on my localhost. I was able to import the react-markdown file correctly but I think thats the problem at this point.

Check out the link here [CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/brianbier/pen/BLBwjV?editors=0110)

```
class ChangeText extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
      value: 'Heading\n=======\n\nSub-heading\n-----------\n \n### Another deeper heading\n \nParagraphs are separated\nby a blank line.\n\nLeave 2 spaces at the end of a line to do a  \nline break\n\nText attributes *italic*, **bold**, \n`monospace`, ~~strikethrough~~ .\n\nShopping list:\n\n  * apples\n  * oranges\n  * pears\n\nNumbered list:\n\n  1. apples\n  2. oranges\n  3. pears\n\nThe rain---not the reign---in\nSpain.\n\n *[Herman Fassett](https://freecodecamp.com/hermanfassett)*'
    }
  }
  updateValue(event){
    let newMarkdown = event.target.value
    this.setState({
      value: newMarkdown
    })
  }

  rawMarkUp(value){
  var rawMarkup = marked(value, {sanitize: true});
  return { __html: rawMarkup };

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <h4>Write your text here and see the mark down -></h4>
             <textarea  className="form-control" width='300' ref="textarea" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.updateValue.bind(this)}/>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">
             <h4>Markdown Result</h4>
            {/* <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkUp(this.state.markdown)}></div> */}
            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkUp(this.state.value)}></span>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
React.render(<ChangeText />,document.getElementById("container"));
```